# Bash Script: Delete characters in string up to and including a phrase?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, xdotool

I have a bash script for hiding X11 windows. I want to be able to find what window the mouse is positioned over and unmap that window.

Using `xdotool` I've gotten a way to find the window ID:

`$ xdotool getmouselocation`

`x:392 y:344 screen:0 window:54799020`

I want to trim this line to just `54799020`.
(I want to remove everything up to and including `window:`.)

Is there a way to do this? I have very little experience with `tr` and `sed`. I've used `sed` to remove text before, but I need to also remove the mouse coordinates, which are not always the same.

Comment: awk with field seperator `:` and pull column 4

Comment: That's... rather interesting. Never really used `awk` though. I guess I could read the manpage and figure it out.

Comment: in most cases parsing "record" like files/text will work better with awk -- that is what it is designed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
sed 's/.*window:\(.*\)/\1/g' file
```

In your case,

```
xdotool getmouselocation | sed 's/.*window:\(.*\)/\1/g'
```

Example:

```
$ echo "x:392 y:344 screen:0 window:54799020" | sed 's/.*window:\(.*\)/\1/g'
54799020
```

Comment: Thanks :) This worked well.  I love `sed`! (but I used `xdotool getmouselocation | sed 's/.*window:\(.*\)/\1/g'`). I can't accept this answer for 9 minutes, but I will mark it then. Until then, +1. (edit: i see you added my command to the list.) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

awk with field seperator `:` and grab column 4

You can use an awk script like this

```
#!/bin/awk
BEGIN { FS=":";}
print $5
```

or run it on the command line.

```
awk -F':' '{print $5}' file
```

and in your case

```
xdotool getmouselocation | awk -F':' '{print $5}' -
```

set it to a variable (which is probably what you are doing)

```
WINDOWLOC=`xdotool getmouselocation | awk -F':' '{print $5}' -`
```

or

```
WINDOWLOC=$(xdotool getmouselocation | awk -F':' '{print $5}' -)
```

Comment: This would work too, but I'm in a bash script and really don't want to make a whole other file just for this. It does work, though. +1

Comment: @Wyatt8740 You can run it as a stand alone one-liner. Check the update.

Comment: @JS웃 - I was going to include the one-line with an edit but Amazon rang the doorbell -- thanks

Comment: Already marked the other one as answer - sorry :\ I don't want to take someone's points away. But I +1ed. Thank you :)

Comment: @Wyatt8740 - That is sweet -- no worries, I don't care, got plenty of points.  I just like answering questions.  Please enjoy SO

Comment: @Hogan You're welcome. Using `PRINT` will not work due to upper-case.

Comment: and should be `print $5` to get OP's desired output.

Comment: @JS웃 - you're right... awk is 1 based not 0 based (`$0` is the whole line)

Comment: Quick question - is `awk` usually provided in a standard GNU/linux system? I remember there was some really simple tool that ubuntu, for example, left out. maybe it was `tr`?

Comment: @Wyatt8740 - awk is in everything as far as I know. (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/awk.1posix.html)

Comment: I figured out what it was. OS X doesn't have `awk`.

Comment: @Wyatt8740 - Maybe your machine is not setup right? --> https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/awk.1.html

Answer (score 2):

For the general case in your question title, this can be done in bash alone in at least two ways.

One uses [bash string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

```
# ${VARIABLE##pattern} trims the longest match from the start of the variable.
# This assumes that "window:nnnnnn" is the last property returned.

DOTOOL_OUTPUT=$(xdotool getmouselocation)
WINDOW_HANDLE=${DOTOOL_OUTPUT##*window:}
```

As a mnemonic, `#` is to the left of `$` on the keyboard and trims the start of the string; `%` is to the right of `$` and trims the end of the string. `#` and `%` trim the shortest pattern match; `##` and `%%` trim the longest.

The other way uses [bash regular expression matching](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver3.html#REGEXMATCHREF):

```
# Within bash's [[ ]] construct, which is a built-in replacement for
# test and [ ], you can use =~ to match regular expressions. Their
# matching groups will be listed in the BASH_REMATCH array.

# Accessing arrays in bash requires braces (i.e. ${ } syntax).

DOTOOL_OUTPUT=$(xdotool getmouselocation)
if [[ $XDOTOOL_OUTPUT =~ window:([0-9]+) ]]; then
  WINDOW_HANDLE=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```